# How to convert a list of 2-tuples to a list of their first elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I have a list like this-

```
[(1, 3),(2, 2)]
```

I like to convert it to-

```
[1,2]
```

What I am doing is-

```
c = [(1, 3),(2, 2)]
output = []
for a,b in c:
    output.append(a)
return output
```

Is there any way for doing this in 1 line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `list-comprehension`

```
output = [a for a,_ in c]
```

Here the `_`, corresponding to the `b` used in the question, is the conventional name given to a dummy variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and getting the first element from each tuple:

```
c = [(1, 3),(2, 2)]

print([i[0] for i in c])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way doing this is:

```
[x[0] for x in c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the zip() function.

```
b = [*list(zip(*a))[0]]
```

Comment: I suspect that this is added for sake of offering something different from what has already been suggested, but not only is the list comprehension more readable, it is also faster. Playing with `timeit`, I found the zip method to take about 3x as long for list of size 1000000, and about 2x as long for list of size 10.